# Can the entropy of mixing be negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability

There is a general notion that the entropy of mixing should always be positive (or zero if we are mixing exactly the same stuff). However, I have a seeming counterexample at hand.

Consider a box partitioned into volumes $V_1$ and $V_2$ both of which are kept at the same temperature and pressure. Suppose that $V_1$ is filled with a solution (of ideal gases) containing $N_a$ particles of the solvent species $a$ and $N_b$ particles of the solute species $b$. Now suppose that $V_2$ is filled with the same solution containing the same amount of solvent but $N_c$ particles of solute $b$. By ideal gas law, this means that
\begin{equation}
\frac{N_a + N_b}{V_1} = \frac{N_a + N_c}{V_2} = \frac{2N_a + N_b + N_c}{V_1 + V_2}\,.
\end{equation}

The entropy of mixing is given by
\begin{align}
\Delta S &= -k \ln \left(4^{N_a} \frac{\left(N_b+N_c\right)^{N_b+N_c}}{N_b^{N_b}N_c^{N_c}} \left(\frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2} \right)^{N_a+N_b}\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1+V_2} \right)^{N_a+N_c} \right) \\
&= -2kN_a\ln2 + k \sum_{x=b,c} \left(N_x\ln \frac{N_x}{N_b+N_c} - ({N_a+N_x})\ln \left(c_a + c_x \right) \right)  \,,
\end{align}
where $c_x \equiv N_x/(2N_a + N_b + N_c)$ is the molar fraction of component $x$. In terms of molar concentrations $n_a,n_b$ and $n_c$, one can rewrite the above as follows.
\begin{equation}
\Delta S = -2R\ n_a\ln2 + R \sum_{x=b,c} \left(n_x\ln \frac{n_x}{n_b+n_c} - ({n_a+n_x})\ln \left(c_a + c_x \right) \right)\,.
\end{equation}
Notice that the first term above is negative. The remain contribution could be positive or negative depending on the difference. However, the odd thing is that this change in entropy could, in general, be negative (what prevents it?). That is very counter-intuitive!

I could be mistaken in either of three ways:

1. There is a proof that shows that the change in entropy in the example given above is indeed non-negative.
2. It is negative due to the wrong assumption that the entropy of the system is expressed as I have expressed. But I have used the well-known entropy for a grand canonical ensemble and its additivity to derive the result. Is that not applicable here? Why?
3. It is negative due to the false expression of the ideal gas law. If so, why?

Can someone tell me which of the three it is and why? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to check your work, try seeing if it works in the case $N_b = N_c = 0$. I don't think it's right even in that case!

Comment: @knzhou They are not linear in $N_a$ because there are terms with $N_a$ inside a logarithm. Also, with $N_b = N_c = 0$, as with any $N_b = N_c$, the change in entropy is zero.

Comment: Would it help if someone provided the entropy of mixing, determined using classical thermodynamics?

Comment: You have overcomplicated things with your notation. The result is non-negative. There is no need to make $N_a$ the same in both boxes, this just makes the result look less obvious. Work through it again, but define (say) $N_a\rightarrow A_1$ in box 1, $N_a\rightarrow A_2$ in box 2, $N_b\rightarrow B_1$, $N_c\rightarrow B_2$. You will get a sum of two independent, standard, non-negative entropy changes, one for each species.

Comment: @LonelyProf Nothing changes morally. Similar calculation replaces $-2k A_1 \ln 2$ with $+k \sum_{x=1,2} A_x \ln \frac{A_x}{A_1 + A_2}$ (which is negative, BTW), keeping everything else the same. I don't "get a sum of two independent, standard, non-negative entropy changes, one for each species." Could you please show us what you get?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe I have provided an answer along the lines I suggested. This basically rewrites your formulae, down to your *first* expression for $S_{\text{final}}$, in the more symmetrical form which I believe makes things more clear. I'm not going to check your working beyond that, as this site isn't really intended to handle "check my work" questions. Maybe you made a slip, maybe not. In any case, the entropy change cannot be negative.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: @KyleKanos This is not really a "check my work" problem. The physical principle debated by a seeming counterexample is that entropy of mixing should always be positive. It is possible that I went wrong in expressing the ideal gas law or by assuming a wrong formula for the entropy. In any case, a lot of relevant physics can be learnt from the answers by future readers.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe you've literally posted "this is my problem. this is my work. what did i do wrong" which is a "check my work" problem, as stated.

Comment: @KyleKanos While I agree that the question can be worded in a better way, just because a question seems like a "check my work" problem does not mean it does not contain discussion of useful physical principles. I am not asking if I missed a minus sign somewhere, because I know I didn't. I am asking in which physical assumption did I go wrong. I appreciate your efforts to keep the site clean, but please don't be too pedantic in your approach to close off useful discussions that can help others as well! Thanks. :)

Comment: Frankly, it's a HW question according to site rules. And since Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, it's not on topic here, But if you do want that kind of help, you can [take a look at this thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/25301) for a list of free online homework help resources.

Comment: @KyleKanos Frankly, I disagree. From the site rules, "Do my homework"-type physics questions [like] "A 4kg ball is traveling at 8m/s in the x direction, how do I find..." [sic] are discouraged. I do not see how a general question like "Can the entropy of mixing be negative?" can ever be misconstrued as a homework question!

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe you've posted work & asked us to check it. Your question literally is "Where did I go wrong?" It's right there at the end. If you want to ask a *different* question, ask it instead. But as you've written it, this is off-topic.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look over the answer I presented.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I appreciate your answer. I will go through it in detail tonight. I would like to find out where the difference comes from. :)

Comment: I have been able to show that there actually is no difference.  I was mistaken when I said that my result does not match yours.  If you work through the algebra, you will find that it actually does match yours precisely.  So the only thing I have added was the proof that the entropy change is positive.

Comment: Oh, that's great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated,
I prefer to use $A_1$, $B_1$ for the initial numbers of atoms of each species in the box with volume $V_1$,
and $A_2$, $B_2$ for the corresponding numbers in $V_2$.
Of course, you can set $A_1=A_2$ afterwards.
But this highlights the symmetry and simplifies the proof.

My version of your equations for the initial and final entropies is
\begin{align*}
S_{\mathrm{init}}/k &= A_1 \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_1}{A_1\lambda_a^3}\right) 
+ B_1 \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_1}{B_1\lambda_b^3}\right)\\ 
& + A_2 \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_2}{A_2\lambda_a^3}\right) 
+ B_2 \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_2}{B_2\lambda_b^3}\right) ,
\\
S_{\mathrm{final}}/k &= 
(A_1+A_2) \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_1+V_2}{(A_1+A_2)\lambda_a^3}\right) 
\\
&+ (B_1 + B_2) \left(\frac{5}{2} + \ln \frac{V_1+V_2}{(B_1 + B_2)\lambda_b^3}\right) .
\end{align*}
In calculating the difference, the $5/2$ terms and the de Broglie wavelengths all cancel, and the result can be expressed as a sum of two terms, each applying to one of the two species:
\begin{align*}
\Delta S/k &= 
(A_1+A_2)\ln\left(\frac{V_1+V_2}{A_1+A_2}\right)
-A_1\ln\left(\frac{V_1}{A_1}\right) -A_2\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{A_2}\right) 
\\
&+
(B_1+B_2)\ln\left(\frac{V_1+V_2}{B_1+B_2}\right)
-B_1\ln\left(\frac{V_1}{B_1}\right) -B_2\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{B_2}\right) 
\\
& \equiv \Delta S_A/k + \Delta S_B/k .
\end{align*} 
I believe that this is equivalent to your first equation for $\Delta S$, before you start introducing molar fractions and molar concentrations;
your factor $4^{N_a}$ has become the appropriate more general formula involving $A_1$ and $A_2$, analogous to your factor
involving $N_b$ and $N_c$.
(Technically I shouldn't write these log terms separately, because the argument of log should be dimensionless, but it is more readable this way. I'll recombine them in the equation below.)

This equation for $\Delta S$ makes sense because,
for this simple example, 
"mixing" really means "expansion" of each of the (independent) gases.
We could do the mixing in two separate steps,
using a semi-permeable membrane,
and the positive entropy change would drive both steps.
Both the "A" term and the "B" term are non-negative. Let's just look at $\Delta S_A$.
Define
$$
x_1=\frac{A_1}{A_1+A_2}, \quad x_2=\frac{A_2}{A_1+A_2}, \quad
\text{so}\quad x_1+x_2=1
$$
and also define $v_1=V_1/A_1$ and $v_2=V_2/A_2$. Notice that
$$
\frac{V_1+V_2}{A_1+A_2} = x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 .
$$
Then
$$
\Delta S_A/k = (A_1+A_2) \ln \left(\frac{x_1v_1+x_2v_2}{v_1^{x_1}v_2^{x_2}}\right) .
$$
This is guaranteed to be non-negative because of the general inequality
$$
x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 \geq v_1^{x_1}\,v_2^{x_2} \qquad
\text{given $x_1+x_2=1$}
$$
which you can find on the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Geometric_mean) Wikipedia page
(it goes by several names, such as [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),
following from the concave property of the log function,
or [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality)).

So both $\Delta S_A$ and $\Delta S_B$, and hence $\Delta S$,
are non-negative.

Comment: Thanks. So, I think the culprit is the substitution according to $\frac{A_1 + B_1}{V_1} = \frac{A_2 + B_2}{V_2} = \frac{A_1 + A_2 + B_1 + B_2}{V_1 + V_2}$. If it is indeed wrong, how does the ideal gas law appear in this case?

Comment: Well, yes, I derived this result without making that assumption (of equal pressures in the two compartments). I'm still assuming that the gases are ideal and the temperatures are the same. There is nothing to stop you choosing volumes and particle numbers to satisfy that equation. I don't think that it is wrong. My question would be, can you give an example of particle numbers and volumes that make your expressions for the entropy change negative?

Comment: Indeed, it is positive for all positive values of the number of particles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I get the following result which is equivalent to your final answer:

$$\Delta S=R\left[-2n_a\ln{2}+n_a\ln{\frac{(2n_a+n_b+n_c)^2}{(n_a+n_b)(n_a+n_c)}}+n_b\ln{\frac{n_b(2n_a+n_b+n_c)}{(n_a+n_b)(n_b+n_c)}}+n_c\ln{\frac{n_c(2n_a+n_b+n_c)}{(n_a+n_c)(n_b+n_c)}}\right]$$

**ADDENDUM**

The partial molar entropy of a given species in an ideal gas mixture is the same as that of the pure species at the same temperature as the mixture and at the partial pressure of the species in the mixture.  Therefore, we have $$\bar{S}=S^0(T,P)-R\ln{\frac{p}{P}}=S^0(T,P)-R\ln{x}$$where $S^0(T,P)$ is the  is the entropy of the pure species at the temperature T and total pressure P and x is the mole fraction in the mixture.

Let the subscript 1 refer to species A, and the subscript 2 refer to species B,C.  So, in the initial mixtures, 
$$S_{initial}=n_a\left(S_1^0-R\ln{\frac{n_a}{(n_a+n_b)}}\right)+n_a\left(S_1^0-R\ln{\frac{n_a}{(n_a+n_c)}}\right)+n_b\left(S_2^0-R\ln{\frac{n_b}{(n_a+n_b)}}\right)+n_c\left(S_2^0-R\ln{\frac{n_c}{(n_a+n_c)}}\right)$$
Similarly, in the final mixture,
$$S_{final}=2n_a\left(S_1^0-R\ln{\frac{2n_a}{(2n_a+n_b+n_c)}}\right)+(n_b+n_c)\left(S_2^0-R\ln{\frac{(n_b+n_c)}{(2n_a+n_b+n_c)}}\right)$$
From this it follows that the entropy of mixing is given by $$\Delta S=S_{final}-S_{initial}$$This reduces to the expression I gave above.

**PROVING THAT THE ENTROPY INCREASES**

We begin by making the following substitutions into the equation for the entropy change:
$$\lambda=\frac{n_b+n_c}{2}$$
$$\xi=\frac{n_b-n_c}{2}$$ We will show that the entropy change is positive definite in $\xi$.  Substituting, we obtain:
$$\frac{\Delta S}{R}=\lambda\ln{\left[1-\left(\frac{\xi}{\lambda}\right)^2\right]}-(\lambda+n_a)\ln{\left[1-\left(\frac{\xi}{\lambda+n_a}\right)^2\right]}+\xi\left[\ln{\frac{\left(1+\frac{\xi}{\lambda}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{\xi}{\lambda}\right)}}-\ln{\frac{\left(1+\frac{\xi}{\lambda+n_a}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{\xi}{\lambda+n_a}\right)}}\right]$$
If we expand this in a Taylor series in $\xi$, we obtain:
$$\frac{\Delta S}{R}=\lambda\left(\alpha^2+\frac{\alpha^4}{6}+\frac{\alpha^6}{15}...\right)-(\lambda+n_a)\left(\beta^2+\frac{\beta^4}{6}+\frac{\beta^6}{15}...\right)$$where $$\alpha=\frac{\xi}{\lambda}$$and$$\beta=\frac{\xi}{\lambda+n_a}$$
This can readily be seen to be positive definite since $\beta<\alpha$.  For example, if we include only the first terms in the expansions, we obtain:
$$\frac{\Delta S}{R}\approx n_a\frac{\xi^2}{\lambda(\lambda+n_a)}=n_a\frac{(n_b-n_c)^2}{(n_b+n_c)(2n_a+n_b+n_c)}$$In short, the contribution of each term in the negative expansion is smaller than that of the corresponding term in the positive expansion.

Comment: I am sure I did not make a mistake in computing the difference. I verified my calculations even with Mathematica. It checks out. So, which of the following do you contest: (1) the first identity I wrote down as an expression of the ideal gas law, or (2) the formula I used for the entropy of a grand canonical ensemble (cf. Schwabl Ch.2 Eq.2.7.27 for details)?

Comment: I arrived at this result using classical thermo.

Comment: I am doing classical thermodynamics as well. So, where do we differ? Anyway, even with your answer, is it possible for the change in entropy to be negative?

Comment: I think I can prove that it’s not possible.

Comment: Please. I would appreciate that. Show us your derivation as well. Thanks.

Comment: I added the derivation.  I'll work on presenting the proof that the entropy of mixing is positive definite later.

Comment: Proof of positive definiteness also added.

Comment: Have you checked over my proof of positive definiteness yet?

Comment: Yes, it is nice. Thanks! I selected the other answer because I found it more elegant. But your answer is as much valuable. :)

Comment: I guess elegance is in the eye of the beholder.